# Is it possible in Swift to execute code at runtime from a string?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, plist

I have a list of items that have conditions associated with them. I want to store this list of items and their conditions in a plist rather than hardcode them into a .swift file.

The only problem with that is that there needs to a function associated with each item to check a condition. Here is what it might look like hardcoded:

```
let myJobStep1 = JobStep(heading: "My Heading", description: "This is the description", warningText: "", condition_check: { () -> Bool in
    return (self.trayColor == .Blue) || (self.trayColor == .Red)
})

let myJobStep2 = JobStep(heading: "My Heading", description: "Another description", warningText: "", condition_check: { () -> Bool in
    return (self.trayColor == .Green)
})
```

The question is how to encapsulate the function that is checking conditions in a string that can be in a plist file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you're going to come is `NSPredicate` and/or `NSExpression` which give you a limited ability to dynamically evaluate expressions given as strings.

```
enum Colors : Int {
    case Red = 1
    case Green = 2
    case Blue = 3
}

class Line : NSObject {
    var lineColor : Int

    init(lineColor:Colors) {
        self.lineColor = lineColor.rawValue
    }
}

let red = Line(lineColor: .Red)
let green = Line(lineColor: .Green)

let basic = NSPredicate(format: "self.lineColor == $Red")
let test = basic.predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(["Red":Colors.Red.rawValue])

test.evaluateWithObject(red)       // true
test.evaluateWithObject(green)     // false
```

Since `NSExpression` is based on Objective-C and Key Values, there are some restrictions:

1. The object being evaluated must be derived from `NSObject`.
2. Properties must be automatically translatable to `AnyObject`, hence we store the int and not the Color.  Note that you could probably handle this a little differently by using a derived property.
3. The substitution dictionary must be `[String:AnyObject]` so you'll have to use the enum raw value instead of the enum value itself.

Comment: You don't need mutable properties for KVC: `class Foo: NSObject { let val = "Bar" }; let f = Foo(); f.valueForKey("val")` works just fine. (And so do some longer variants that don't fit in a comment.)

Comment: So it does, for some reason it didn't work for me initially, but that could well have been because I started with it being type Colors.

Comment: Thank you for the full example and for showing how it is possible with enum values. Between your and @rickster's answer, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html)!

The functional programming constructs in Swift — `map`, `filter`, shorthand closures, etc. — are great tools for when you want to express relationships between data *in imperative code*. But they aren't the only way to look at such problems.

In particular, it's often useful to be able to express relationships between data *as data*:

- If you're loading a bunch of data model objects from a simple file representation, you can encode their relationships as such, too.
- If you're encoding data relationships as data, you can load / update / download them at runtime, instead of changing code and shipping a new app binary.
- If you're dealing with a backend database / web service / RDBMS / ORM (CloudKit, Core Data, etc), you want a way to express things like filters, queries, sort orders, and relationships that you can pass to the backend and let the big expensive data-crunching operations happen there.

This is what [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html) (and, relatedly, [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/index.html)) are for. Unlike a filter / comparison closure, the essential logic associated with a predicate can be data, not code. So you can have a data source that looks like this:

```
[
    "heading": "My Heading",
    "description": "This is the description",
    "condition": "trayColor == \"Blue\" || trayColor == \"Red\""
]
```

Then you can create predicates from your data source:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: item.condition)
```

And use them to test conditions on individual objects, filter collections, etc:

```
predicate.evaluateWithObject(item)
(items as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

*Edit:* @DavidBerry beat me to the punch. This is more of a "why" / high-level answer, but his has some good details on bits like setting up a mapping between enum cases, data-file contents, and predicate formats.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thank you! I didn't even know that what I was looking for had a specific name - NSPredicate. This is very helpful.

Do you think it would be possible for a predicate to contain an enum value? (i.e. `trayColor == TrayColor.Blue` or `trayColor == .Blue`)? I suppose I can just try it out and find it out...

Comment: Enums are a Swift thing, and NSPredicate is an ObjC-derived API. There are various ways around this — @DavidBerry shows one in his answer. Another option is for your class to expose a second (computed) property that represents the enum value as an int or string or something.